# Где найти документацию implementation-defined поведения у Clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Для GCC можно легко найти документацию для implementation-defined поведения [здесь](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior) и [здесь](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Implementation.html). Есть ли такая документация у Clang? Если нет, то получается, что он не соответствует стандарту?

Comment: Место расположения документации про implementation-defined поведение компилятора implementation-defined.

Comment: @AlexGlebe логично :D Тогда можно и не публиковать ничего, у разработчика на компе только оставить документацию, тоже будет соответствовать "где-то задокументировано")